# Why does the Android tag on Stack Overflow have an icon, while other tags don't?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just writing a question related to Android. And I noticed that Stack Overflow has an icon for the Android tag, but it doesn't have an icon for any other tag I attached to the question. Why is that?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/204841

Comment: its not the only tag icon, off the top of my ahead there is icons for [SQL-Server] and [firebase]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags are sponsored.

See [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/engagement/solutions/tag-sponsorship) for the official announcement by SO.

In addition to one's logo there, organizations sponsoring a tag get the following benefits (from the link above):

> During a typical campaign, your ads will appear on your desired technology tag 25% of the time. Tag Sponsorships give you 50% of this share of voice on a technology tag, giving you increased exposure to the specific programming languages you’re targeting.

and

> Create a custom ad unit to showcase at the top of a technology tag’s main page on Stack Overflow, where you can include your company’s logo and five (5) links to promote your messaging further.